# homebrew don't upgrade installed dependency

Tags: macos, erlang, elixir, homebrew

I'm trying to install an earlier version of Elixir, using my own local tap, but when I do that, it installs a newer version of erlang. I'm trying to keep it at `erlang@23`, but when I install elixir, it updates it to 24, even though the elixir version itself is compatible with earlier erlang versions.

Comment: Use https://asdf-vm.com/#/ to manage versions.

Comment: I would advice to use kerl and kiex for managing different versions of erlang and elixir